# Problem with this $\frac{d}{dx}(y^3)$

Tags: derivatives

How do you differentiate this equation with respect to $x$? 
$$x^2=xy^3+2$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(xy^3)+\frac{d}{dx}(2)$$

$$2x=x\frac{d}{dx}(y^3)+y^3\frac{d}{dx}(x)+0$$

$$2x=x\frac{d}{dx}(y^3)+y^3$$

Here is the problem I am facing with, $$\frac{d}{dx}(y^3)?$$

this $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)=3x^2$ it is understandable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the chain rule and get

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}y^3 = 3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that
$$ \frac{d}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{d}{dx} $$
by the chain rule. Then we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}y^3 = \frac{dy}{dx} y^3 \cdot \frac{d}{dy} = 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx}. $$
So
$$ \frac{d}{dx} y^3 = 3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}.$$
If you are interested in what the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is, then you can solve for it as if it was a variable. It should come out to be a function in terms of $x$ and $y$.